# Textarea position in different resolution

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a homework for an internship and I have to replicate a webpage from a picture. Here's their picture and beside it is what I got so far: [image+image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrvkf.jpg)

I don't know how to put those `textarea` near the text when the resolution is higher. At 1024x768 (which is the minimum imposed) it looks good, but when I maximize the window, this happens. :/

Here's the code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQmM4/). I'm not sure about it, but could someone help? 
Cheers!

Comment: I don't see a problem, what do you mean?

Comment: The gap between the writing and the textarea is too large, compared with the original picture. This happens when I maximize the window, it gets further and further away.

Comment: Haha, ok, am on a notebook, just starts to happen what you say, when the window is at maximum I guess, let me see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried to hackish solve the hackish.

Because:

- You had the `<textarea>` inside a `<p>`.
- I took them out and put a `div` around.
- The textarea had `float: right` inline, and `float: left` in the stylesheet. The inline won due to [specificity](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fspecifics-on-css-specificity%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG1eIkxQSAPNOr7dGLyjsyOq1qfww).
- The float does not give the parent container a height (without "clearfix") so I took
  `display: inline-block`.

I tried to solve it with:

```
p.label {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
}

.intro {
width:82%;
display: inline-block;
background-color:#fff;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

All that said, I still have the 12" notebook screen and do not know if it *works* and if you *like* it. Please give me a shot, if something is not working.

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jQmM4/1/

Comment: It works and then it doesn't. If I put the .label to all the other points I have, it messes the textareas. I need to find a way to align them vertically, on the same line and fix that! Only the right margin should move. Btw, thank you. FB?

Comment: Eah, yeah, well, I did not tell you so far, that you have to change the whole HTML markup as in the first example. ;) FB, yeah, look at my  profile here and go on my website. Find my name and (if that does not work) put my artist name in between. ;) 1